# Como acessar um servidor local de um dispositivo Android

Tags: android, django, url, localhost

Eu tenho um servidor em Django rodando em meu computador "localhost:8000/posts", e estou criando um cliente em Android para acessar o mesmo.

Depurando a minha aplicação em um dispositivo real, eu tentei acessar pelo meu IPv4 sabendo que tanto o computador quanto o celular estão na mesma subrede "192.168.X.X:8000/posts", porém não consigo acessar este link pelo navegador do celular.

Chequei a opção "chrome://inspect/" do Google Chrome, porém não sei como isto pode me ajudar ou se pode me ajudar.

Contudo, alguem sabe que é a melhor alternativa para estabelecer esta coneção tanto pelo meu App quanto pelo navegador?

Comment: Adicionou   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> ao AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Você esta tentando acessar via WI-FI?

Comment: Reginaldo, Sim os 2 estão ligados a mesma rede de WI-FI.

Comment: Eu coloquei a Permissão de INTERNET, mas o problema está alem da própria aplicação, uma vez que não consigo acessar meu servidor pelo próprio navegador do celular

Comment: Você consegue acessar o serviço usando o browser de outra maquina da sua rede?

Comment: Nem de outro nem do próprio computador, ele fica apenas carregando

Comment: E você consegue parar e iniciar o serviço no Painel de Controle?

Answer (score 1):

Descobri oque estava acontecendo, eu só consegui acessar pelo host "localhost:8000" ou "127.0.0.1:8000" porque o servidor do Django só estava aceitando acessos locais, uma vez que estartei unicamente com o comando

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Assim quando iniciei o servidor com o comando

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

O mesmo voltou a aceitar conexões pelo meu ip "129.169.x.x:8000"